# XML Starlet Delete custom XMl Node

Tags: xml, text-processing, xmlstarlet

Basically, I have multiple `<video_preprocessors>` & `</video_preprocessors>` in my XML. I want to delete the first `</video_preprocessors>` node and the second `<video_preprocessors>` node how can I achieve it?

```
</video_preprocessors>
      <video_preprocessors>
        <timecode_burnin>
          <font_size>16</font_size>
          <position>top_center</position>
          <prefix/>
        </timecode_burnin>
```

It was located before  `<timecode_burnin>`

Here is the full xml.

https://pastebin.com/sM7saneG

I want to delete `</video_preprocessors>  <video_preprocessors>`  before `<timecode_burnin>`

Thank you very much.

Comment: @jojo, you can NOT delete `<video_preprocessors>` node without deleting `timecode_burnin` - because `timecode_burnin` is a child node of `<video_preprocessors>` node in this case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Analyzing your expected output/result I've come up to conclusion that it requires 2 actions:

**1**)  move `timecode_burnin` node to the previous sibling node `video_preprocessors`

**2**)  delete the *"old"* `video_preprocessors` node that initially contained `timecode_burnin` node

```
xmlstarlet ed -m "//video_preprocessors/timecode_burnin" \
"//video_preprocessors/timecode_burnin/../preceding-sibling::video_preprocessors" \
-d "//video_preprocessors[timecode_burnin]/following-sibling::video_preprocessors" test.xml
```

---

The above command will output the expected result.

The crucial fragment after processing:

```
...
<codec>h.264</codec>
      <video_preprocessors>
        <deinterlacer>
          <algorithm>interpolate</algorithm>
          <deinterlace_mode>Deinterlace</deinterlace_mode>
          <force>false</force>
        </deinterlacer>
        <timecode_burnin>
          <font_size>16</font_size>
          <position>top_center</position>
          <prefix/>
        </timecode_burnin>
      </video_preprocessors>
    </video_description>    
...
```

---

To modify the file *inplace* - add global `-L` option :
`xmlstarlet ed -L -m ...`